# Looking for a book on windows C++ GUI programming

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface

I know this question has been asked a lot, but I want to find a book on windows programming with C++ that specifically focuses on GUIs. I picked up a book on C++ game programming, and in the begging it covered a little bit of windows GUI programming. So now I would like to be able to get a little more in depth on the subject. Any suggestions?

P.S.
   I'm talking about win32 programs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Programming Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231995X) is the classic and probably a good place to start.

Comment: Petzold's book has been the gold-standard since Windows GUI coding has existed.  I heartily agree.